# Set User Name and Password from Txt file using bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have an env.txt file in the following format:

```
lDRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};
PORT=1433;
SERVER=serveename;
DATABASE=db;
UID=username;
PWD=password!
```

I have a git bash script (.sh) that requires the UID and PWD from that file. I was thinking about getting it by the last/second last line number. How do I do this/ is there a better way (say looking for UID and PWD and assigning the git bash variable that way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's lots of ways to do this. You could use `awk` which I would personally use since it's sort of like an x-acto knife for this type of thing:

```
uid=$(awk -F"[=;]" '/UID/{print $2}' env.txt)
pwd=$(awk -F"[=;]" '/PWD/{print $2}' env.txt)
```

Or `grep` and `sed`. `sed` is nice because it allows you to get very specific about the piece of info you want to cut from the line, but it's regex which has its learning curve:

```
uid=$(grep "UID" env.txt | sed -r 's/^.*=(.*)(;|$)/\1/g' )
pwd=$(grep "PWD" env.txt | sed -r 's/^.*=(.*)(;|$)/\1/g' )
```

As @JamesK noted in the comments you can use `sed` and have it do the search instead of `grep`. This is super nice and I would definitely choose this instead of the `grep | sed`.

```
uid=$(sed -nr '/UID/s/^.*=(.*)(;|$)/\1/gp' )
pwd=$(sed -nr '/PWD/s/^.*=(.*)(;|$)/\1/gp' )
```

Or `grep` and `cut`. Bleh... we can all do better, but sometimes we just want to `grep` and `cut` and not have to think about it:

```
uid=$(grep "UID" env.txt | cut -d"=" -f2 | cut -d";" -f1)
pwd=$(grep "PWD" env.txt | cut -d"=" -f2 | cut -d";" -f1)
```

I definitely wouldn't go by line number though. That looks like and odbc.ini file and the order in which the parameters are listed in each odbc entry are irrelevant.

Comment: Note that you can roll the `grep` into the `sed` invocation: `uid=$(sed -nr '/UID/s/^.*=(.*)(;|$)/\1/gp' )`.  Method of operation is to add the `-n` flag to not print lines by default; only operate on lines matching UID (`/UID/`), and also print the line once you're done with it with `p` at the end.

Comment: @JamesK That's nice. I fumble through `sed` most of the time. I'll definitely remember this though.

Comment: I accepted this as the answer. Do you mind commenting on the positive and negative aspects of each method?

Answer (score 1):

First rename `PWD` to something like `PASSWORD`. `PWD` is a special variable used by the shell. Even better is to use lowercase variable names for all your own variables.

When the password is without special characters (spaces, $, ), you can

```
source env.txt
```

When the password has something special, consider editing the `env.txt`:

```
lDRIVER="{ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}"
PORT="1433"
SERVER="serveename"
DATABASE="db"
UID="username"
PASSWORD="password!"
```

When you are only interested in lowercase uid and passwd, consider selecting only the interesting fields and change the keywords to lowercase

```
source <(sed -rn '/^(UID|PWD)=/ s/([^=]*)/\L\1/p' env.txt)
```

Comment: Yeah, I think UID and PWD are special variables and that is what was screwing me up. I use this file for pyodbc though, and i wonder if they must be called that

Comment: I would hesitate to `source` this file. It reads like an `odbc.ini` which means there may be a `[ODBC NAME]` block hiding in there. Furthermore the parameters are all upper case, as you noted, which can cause issues with the environment variables already in place.

Comment: Yeah... i get Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)') when changing the variable names

Comment: I edited my answer, so you will source the wanted fields only, and changing the keywords in lowercase.

Comment: Yeah... the problem is that the password variable still has to be called PWD (for pyodbc) so changing the variable names isn't an option. If you could assign the output of the source to antoher variable name then it would work